# Graphics remove the top line of a rectangle

Tags: winforms, drawrectangle

On a winform, is there a way to draw a rectangle like this (without top) using the DrawRectangle method or a workaround?

[image: Rectangle without top]

Comment: "or a workaround"  Sure...use DrawRectangle() followed by DrawLine() with the BackColor for the top.  If you can't erase the top because it would undo other drawings, then make three calls to DrawLine() for the sides, or one call to DrawLines() with an Array of Point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `SetClip` method:

```
private void DrawTopless(Graphics g, Rectangle r) {
  g.SetClip(new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width + 1, 10), CombineMode.Exclude);
  g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, r);
  g.ResetClip();
}
```